# Cordova 3.1.0 navigation.connection.type

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3

even with a "dummy" template code it wont work. I get this in Web console

```
Error initializing Network Connection: Class not found:85
```

I installed the plugin via plugman.

Tested on Androids: Samsung Galaxy SII(4.1.2) and Samsung Galaxy SIII (4.1.2)

Here is the dummy code: (it alerts "unknown" in any case whether there is any type of data connection or none)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        var deviceInfo = function(){
            alert(navigator.connection.type);
        }

        function init(){
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceInfo, true);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">

</body>
</html>
```

Cheers!

Comment: Just checked on another device and it is working. No idea why it doesn't work. It is a few hours since I last ran. Since then I did the following:

1. Tried to access google and there were certificate errors. So I found out that the system time was wrong. But in the process of fixing:
2. Reset play to the original version including play services

Now other applications are working fine. Doesn't seem to be a cordova issue.

Comment: A factory reset didn't fix it. So I was wrong, should be a cordova issue.

Comment: That's scary, I removed android and added, and the error is still the same (cordova platform remove android/add android)

Comment: cordova plugin remove org.apache.cordova.network-information 
takes away the error.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the connection properties you need to install the network information plugin as described in the docs:
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html#Connection

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer, but like i said above i have already installed it via plugman http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/plugin_ref_plugman.md.html as the cordova cli command plugin didnt work for me...

Comment: Even I get the same error. I ran an older version of the application which "worked" and even that won't work. Now I am confused!